# Downloading a file from SFTP site - Issue in converting InputStream to DataHandler

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, java-io

I am developing a JAX-WS Web Service to download a file from a SFTP Site. I use the following code to read the file.

```
channelSftp.cd(sftpHostPath); //sftpHostPath = Path from where file is to be downloaded
inputStream = channelSftp.get(fileName + "." + fileExtn);
```

which returns an object of `java.io.InputStream`. This object needs to be returned by the web service as a `DataHandler` object.

To achieve this, I created a class `InputStreamDataSource` which implements `DataSource` and used it to create the object of `DataHander` as

```
returnFile = new DataHandler(new InputStreamDataSource(inputStream));
```

which in turn is returned by the Web Method.

Now, while running the code from SoapUI by enabling MTOM, I get the following output.

[image: SoapUI Output]

Please note in the attachment that the file size is 0 and the file name is also not specific.

**What is the possible reason for this and a suitable workaround to overcome the problem?**

**NOTE** : ***The file needs to be returned as `DataHandler` itself (as an attachment) without using the `java.io.File` object. Also I want to avoid using any third party jar.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by creating a `DataHandler` using `byte` array.

```
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            while( (readCount = bufferedInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            }
            returnFile = new DataHandler(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), "application/octet-stream");
```